# SimpleMemberShipProvider, Using multiple PropertyValues with custom Database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am creating a Log in scheme using `SimpleMembershipProvider` in MVC4. I wanted a little more control than what i get with the out of the box `AccountControl`. So I have modified the connections to use my database and table, however I would like fields like first name, last name and email to be required.

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndRole(username, password);
```

fails because of the required field types. I have found that I can use `PropertyValues` to fix this issue, however I cannot figure out how to make `PropertyValues` equal more than one value.

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(user.Username, user.password, propertyValues: new {firstName = user.firstName});
```

How do I go about using multiple `PropertyValues`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but can you maybe try adding another entry to the `new {}` object you're creating. Something like:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(user.Username, user.password,
                                 propertyValues: new {firstName = user.firstName,
                                                      lastName = user.lastName});
```

Comment: I was trying to add new { firstname = fname } new { lastname = lname} and it was failing. It is always the simple answers that are the hardest for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must add column (firstName & lastName)  to table dbo.UserProfile in aspnet DB (in folder app_data) for using:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new {firstName = user.firstName, lastName = user.lastName});
```